# Difference between sqlserver.nt_username & sqlserver.username

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I am just learning about `SQL Extended Events`.

I have a small event and for actions I have selected both `sqlserver.nt_username` & `sqlserver.username`

When I test connect with a NT account the event captures the NT account in both fields. When I test connect with a SQL Server Authentication account, only the `sqlserver.username` field captures the account, I can understand why the NT field does not capture non-NT accounts.

It looks like `sqlserver.username` captures everything, while `sqlserver.nt_username` is more selective.

Other then what I have mentioned are there any differences between these two?  Is there any case when `sqlserver.nt_username` might capture something NOT captured by `sqlserver.username`?

In this case I am using the event `sqlserver.sql_batch_starting` but my question is for any event.  With SQL versions 2012 to 2017.

**Note:** Both of these fields are actions, so grabbing both increases overhead. While it is probably not significant overhead, I am trying to stay as lite as possible.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Even if you have a username that is different than corresponding login it will register login in case of AD accounts.

Answer (score 0):

In the vast majority of cases, they should match and you only need to capture the "sqlserver.username" field. There could be some cases where the integrated login (the nt_username) is mapped to something else or there's a certificate or something more complicated where it could show you who is logging in and it will map to something different in the username field, but I've never seen this happen on an actual server.

They're separate values because they can be different, but I've never seen a case where they are.