# Authoritative Extend Event object list?

Tags: sql-server, extended-events

I am looking for an authoritative list of objects for extended events, I want to know what version an object becomes available and some clues about what the value really represents.  I have googled and not finding anything comprehensive.

As an example Microsoft shows version history for 
[SQL:BatchStarting Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/sql-batchstarting-event-class?view=sql-server-2014) going back to 2014, but I have used it on SQL 2012 SP4 (with SSMS 17.4)

[image: ScreenShot of link]

Yes I can use `Select * from sys.dm_xe_objects` to get a list of [All the sys.dm_xe_objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-xe-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and while there is a description it is very general.

If I want to learn something like [Difference between sqlserver.nt_username & sqlserver.username](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/225568/21924) there does not seem to be any resources other than comparing results and guessing.

If I write an XEvent, I should have a resource I can use to define what versions of SQL it will run on, I should not need to go trying it on different version to figure it out.

Where can I find an Authoritative Extend Event object list?

Comment: It sounds like you have a great idea and should spearhead that effort :)

Comment: Possibly you should ping Jonathan from sqlskills that will shed more info on what you are looking for. Email him or Paul and they will reply for sure :-)

Comment: I had the same problem. No such documentation could be found.